# Programmatically Re-Use CiviMail Emails

Tags: civimail, api

I am trying to write an extension that monthly will send a series of CiviMai emails. Basically, it would be the same if a user went to the *Sent* mailings and clicked *Re-Use* and sent the email again without any changes to the email at all.

Obviously, I need the email to be sent the first time but after that, I am not sure how I would use the API to duplicate the email and then schedule it to send.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.11.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bottom lines here to get you started:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Mailing/Controller/Send.php

i.e.
`$clone = civicrm_api3('Mailing', 'clone', array('id' => $mid));`
and then follow thru the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

We have an extension that does something similar i.e. injects emails into the civimail queue. If your interested drop me a line.